# Allow web users to dynamically create reports from Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, report

I have a web application with a Postgresql backend. For the sake of simplicity, lets say its a single table with web server logs (in reality there is a mix of tables and references). As my users have different needs for different data from this table I was thinking about implementing a web frontend where they could run their own reports on demand (i.e. start a background job to run it for  them... some queries may be slow, for instance sub-selecting the same table, aggregation, etc).

Is there any best practices to implement such custom reporting tools?

I was thinking the following scenario as a possible solution:

- The user builds a query and selects the field he/she wants, which is translated into a SQL query
- The SQL selects the query result into a new table with a name like 'report_randomname479472984' which is run as a background job and perhaps even add the tablename to a reports-table with some meta-information about the report.
- The web interface lists all tables with a name starting with 'report_' as available reports OR query the meta-information table about available report_ tables.
- When the user displays a  report, the web page is built as a html-table where each available column from the database is a column in the html-table

Is this a decent approach to creating dynamic on-demand reports from a SQL backend? Is there anything that I need to be aware of when doing this (except for SQL injections)?

Is there any way I can enforce integrity of the meta-table so that there is always a row present for each report_*, and that all rows in the meta-table actually points to a valid report_* table?

Comment: For "meta-table" you could use a `VIEW` over postgresql `pg_catalog`. Something like: `select c.relname FROM pg_class c
WHERE c.relkind = 'r' AND c.relname LIKE 'report_%' `. It will always be consistent.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO the first thing you should do - search for existing solutions for report building, log processing, OLAP, whatever...

There are plenty of them. Both free and paid. And I bet you can find one suitable for your task.

It will save you a lot of time and provide a high quality solution for you clients.

Comment: iReport for example will save much time and pain.

Comment: Although I appreciate your answer, I would still like some insight as how this problem is actually solved, even in existing products. The theory behind this problem is something I am quite interested in learning more about.